# How to update specific map item inside list in a item of Dynamodb using Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, updating

my dynamo Db single item is like this, I want to change `"res=30"` to `"res =35"` inside `"product_rate"` of `"product_id=2"` of primary key `"id==22"`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATUlp.png)

Comment: Do you know the index of the product array that you would like to update? Without knowing the index, Dynamodb doesn't have any feature to update the object inside the array.

Comment: thank you ,when i give index it worked :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DynamoDB update inside an array of objects (nodejs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784042/dynamodb-update-inside-an-array-of-objects-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

[modify node.js code to update listarray item in dynamodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F3tW.png)